# Keep on selecting lines under caret hotkey

Tags: intellij-idea

I created my own key binding for "Select line under caret" action (like it is described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593846/337085).

My hot key is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (default Atom editor binding).

It works, but the problem is - it selects only one line. When I hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and keep pressing <kbd>L</kbd>, it doesn't continue selection to the next lines below.

I tried different ways, installed few plugins, filed IntelliJ IDEA support ticket (no solution so far), tried 3rd party software (BetterTouchTool for Mac), but can't conquer that.

Do you have any ideas I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install the [Missing in Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9257-missing-in-actions) plug-in.
2. Enable Auto Line Selections [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh7MY.png).
3. Assign Cmd+L shortcut to the [Down with Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUDPX.png) action.