# how to duplicate a line keyboard shortcut in code blocks IDE

Tags: codeblocks

Is there any keyboard shortcut for line duplicate in codeblocks IDE, such as in  Netbeans IDE Ctrl+Shift+Up or Down arrow to copy a line in code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select/copy current line without using mouse in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592489/how-to-select-copy-current-line-without-using-mouse-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Ctrl+D** for duplicating line

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Duplicate_Line_Block.html