# IntelIJ copy line without selection

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is a way to just remove the selection when I copy a line by doing ctrl + c on a line

before: I just have my cursor in a line:

[image: before]

after: I just press ctrl + c

[image: after]

I dont like how I have to do an extra step to unselect, there must be a way to just remove the select without removing any functionality. Vscode has it working perfectly but I would love to have the same experience in IntelIJ

Comment: No way, without manually deselecting. To do that, just hit one of the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Ctrl+D to copy a complete line without selecting it.

More info in [JetBrains Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Duplicate_Line_Block.html)

Comment: Although a nice shortcut (thus my upvote), this is more a short comment unless explanation or links given.

Answer (score 0):

To just copy and paste the line, you don't need to select it at all.

Just use action [**Duplicate line or selection**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Duplicate_Line_Block.html) <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>
and [**Move Statement Up/Down**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Moving_Code_Elements.html) <kbd>Alt+Shift+Up</kbd> or <kbd>Alt+Shift+Down</kbd> to the desired position with .

See [JetBrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/08/editor-tips-and-tricks-in-intellij-idea/) :

> Like cut, we can copy a whole line with ⌘C, or Ctrl+C, without having to highlight it first, and paste this too. Sometimes it might be more useful to duplicate the line instead with ⌘D, or Ctrl+D.

When duplicating a line, the line will be copied directly as new line below and cursor is placed where it has been before.

Watch the youtube demo [IntelliJ IDEA Tricks - Lecture 7: Duplicate and Delete Lines (0:41)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lg0KOC-4JyQ&t=41s)

See also:

- [How to select/copy current line without using mouse in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592489/how-to-select-copy-current-line-without-using-mouse-in-intellij-idea)
- JetBrains IDEA help: [Write and edit source code, section *Lines of Code*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#editor_lines_code_blocks)
- Dev.to blog: [IntelliJ style line duplication in Visual Studio Code](https://dev.to/pcdevil/intellij-style-line-duplication-in-visual-studio-code-118o)